# Using an existing bootstrap theme in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, single-page-application

I would like to use this theme in a React single page application using create-react-app.

Theme here:  https://github.com/kristopolous/BOOTSTRA.386

This is my first foray into using an existing theme, there is no clear info in the docs on how to import this specific theme into my project. Also, once I have the theme imported, do I build out the components and look for the specific CSS classes of the bootstrap theme?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

copy the downloaded files to your project's src
in your index.js
add:

`import './bootstra.386-latest-v3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

and it should load the theme's css
also you need to install `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

read more here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction